# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: <an identifier> <a d

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to change the value of "TOTAL_TM_R_PT" where all the times a certain player shows up.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CalculatePlayerTMPoints(Player IN NUMBER,PointNum IN NUMBER) 
DECLARE PtValue INT;
UserNM TABLE; 
BEGIN
    SELECT POINT_VALUE INTO PtValue FROM POINTS WHERE POINTS.POINT_ID = PointNum;     
    SELECT ACCT_USERNAME INTO UserNM FROM ROSTERS WHERE ROSTERS.PLAYER_ID = Player;
    for i in 1..UserNM.count
    loop
        UPDATE TEAM_MANAGER_POINTS
        SET TOTAL_TM_R_PT = TOTAL_TM_R_PT + PtValue 
        WHERE TEAM_MANAGER_POINTS.ACCT_USERNAME = UserNM;
    End loop;
END;
```

This is my error:

```
Error(3,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of  
the following:     ; is with authid as cluster order using external    
deterministic parallel_enable pipelined result_cache    accessible
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a collection type and use `BULK COLLECT INTO` for storing query results in a collection. `AS` keyword was also missing in your code and using `Declare` is not valid.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CalculatePlayerTMPoints(Player IN NUMBER,PointNum IN NUMBER) AS
PtValue INT;
TYPE usertype IS TABLE OF ROSTERS.ACCT_USERNAME%TYPE;
UserNM usertype ; 
BEGIN
    SELECT POINT_VALUE INTO PtValue FROM POINTS WHERE POINTS.POINT_ID = PointNum;     
    SELECT ACCT_USERNAME BULK COLLECT INTO UserNM FROM ROSTERS WHERE ROSTERS.PLAYER_ID = Player;
    for i in 1..UserNM.count
    loop
        UPDATE TEAM_MANAGER_POINTS
        SET TOTAL_TM_R_PT = TOTAL_TM_R_PT + PtValue 
        WHERE  ACCT_USERNAME = UserNM(i);
    End loop;
END;
```